# how can I make my API request get real response during a widget test?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am performing a Widget test on an app. I would like to test when the `circularProgressIndicator` pops up when a button is clicked and a rest request begins. But when widget testing this Scenario my API responds with a 400 immediately making the `circularProgressIndicator` hard to assert during my test. I tried this code:

```
  setUp((){
    HttpOverrides.global = null;
  });
```

But it seems to always make my rest request time out. How can I make a successful api call during widget testing, cause my tests depends on this?